# Directory is not created in API 29 (Android Q)

Tags: java, android, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory, it is work in lower API 29, but not working in API 29. this is my code in mainActivity :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            int writePermissionResult = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            if (writePermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 100);
            }
            else
                createDirectory();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 100)
            if (grantResults[0] == 0)
                createDirectory();
    }

    protected void createDirectory() {
        String dirName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/testdir";

        File file = new File(dirName);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            boolean isCreated = file.mkdir();
            Log.i("CLS", "Created ? " + isCreated + "");
        } else
            Log.i("CLS", "Exists ");
    }
}
```

and uses-permission, 
`android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`, added in manifest file too.
by this code, the directory was created in lower API but mot working in API 29. 
anybody can help? thank you.

Comment: `if (grantResults[0] == 0)` ===> `if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)`. Write readable code please. Is createDirectory() called?

Comment: From api29 and on even ``getExternalStorageDirectory()`` is deprecated. You should switch your implementation to the https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider new api for handling files and documents... just to be prepared for the future

Comment: @blackapps yes, called. but isCreated shows false.

Comment: @Grisgram thank you. I will check

Comment: Your code should work below 29 (Android Q) so there is another problem.

Comment: @blackapps yes. you are right. when I check again, my code work below 29 (Android Q) . So I edited my question.

Comment: On Android Q you cannot create directories in getExternalStorageDirectory(). You cannot even read it. Use getFilesDir() or getExternalFilesDir() instead.